# Unable to see Derived Column Output in Output Tabs of Advanced Editor

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014, derived-column

While practicing an example for Derived Column Transformation on [link](http://www.sqldeft.com/?page_id=164)

I configured Derived Column name Gender to replace the Gender column with expression

`Gender == "M" ? "Male" : "Female"`

As we can see the input length for gender column is 1 but I am converting the column and increasing the length to max of 6. I found that the length can be changed from advanced editor otherwise if I don't change length I get truncation error.

I configured the derived column as following[image]
Now in advanced editor I see the following screen[image]

As you can see the Gender column does not show up in Output columns and the length is also graded out and can not be changed.

Please let me know how I can get the Gender column to show up in Output Derived Column and how to change the length.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, don't use Replace 'Gender' in Derived Column, if you choose **add as a new column** like other derived columns, the system inserts a length equal to 6. 
I hope this help.